# Did the Role annotation. But how is Claim annotation?

Tags: c#, roles, claims-based-identity

I'm following a tutorial that is now teaching me how to use Roles and Claims. First, it teached to use roles so, among other things, I had to put the line below in the **ApplicationUserManager.cs** code:

```
    public const string Administrator = "Admin";
```

As the idea of the project is a IMDB page where only the admin can create new Movie's Genres, I had to put the annotation

```
    [Authorize(Roles = ApplicationUserManager.Administrator)] /* role annotation */
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Api/Genres")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync(GenrePostRequest request)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            await Genre.CreateAsync(request.Name, GetUserId(), db, Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>());
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

before the Post function on the **GenreController.cs** as shown above. Everything worked fine. Everything is good. Now, the tutorial said to add in the **ApplicationUserManager.cs** code those two lines:

```
    public const string IsAdminClaim = "IsAdmin";
    public const string IsAdminClaimValue = "True";
```

so I can use claims.

The tutorial now says "*Update the GenreController's Create action to use the annotation created with the specified claim.*"

I know where the GenreController's Create action is but, how is the claim's annotation supposed to look like?

I know I have a class called **AuthorizationAttribute.cs** that looks something like it:

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }

    public AuthorizationAttribute(string claimType, object claimValue)
    {
        this.ClaimType = claimType;
        this.ClaimValue = claimValue.ToString();
    }
    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        /* some codes */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
I was trying different variations using Authorize just as the Role, but as the class where the claim is build is has the constructor like:

```
public AuthorizationAttribute(string claimType, object claimValue)
{
    this.ClaimType = claimType;
    this.ClaimValue = claimValue.ToString();
}
```

as shown in the question, than the correct annotation is:

```
[Authorization(ApplicationUserManager.IsAdminClaim, ApplicationUserManager.IsAdminClaimValue)]
```

that is, using **Authorization**, NOT **Authorize**.